# How to query a Many-to-Many relation with condition - TypeORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Has a many to many relationship. Category - Product

I want to filter the products by category id.

I checked some examples and wrote this code below, but can't make it work

Can somebody help me out?
thanks

```
@Entity()
export class Product {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToMany(() => Category, {eager: true})
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'product_category'
  })
  categories: Array<Category>;
}


@Entity()
export class Category {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
}


  findProducts(categoryId: number) {
    return this.find({
      join: {alias: 'categories'},
      where: (qb) => {
        qb.where('categories.id = :categoryId', {categoryId: filter.categoryId})
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What does _"can't make it work"_ mean? Do you get error messages? What are the actual and expected results?

Answer (score 3):

I read some documentation and debugged the typeorm code and successfully created the query:

I made some modification on the many to many relation:

```
  @ManyToMany(() => Category, {eager: true})
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'product_category',
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'category_id',
      referencedColumnName: 'id'
    },
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'product_id',
      referencedColumnName: 'id'
    }
  })
  categories: Array<Category>;
```

and the query:

```
{
      relations: ['categories'],
      where: (qb: SelectQueryBuilder<Product>) => {
        qb.where('category_id = :categoryId', {categoryId: categoryId})
      }
}
```

I hope someone else will find it useful

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to be define many-to-many in two way side
its must define in one of side

[https://typeorm.biunav.com/en/many-to-many-relations.html#what-are-many-to-many-relations](http://you%20don%27t%20need%20to%20be%20define%20many-to-many%20in%20two%20way%20side%20its%20must%20define%20in%20one%20of%20side%20%20https://typeorm.biunav.com/en/many-to-many-relations.html#what-are-many-to-many-relations%20and%20better%20way%20use%20the%20Separating%20Entity%20Definition%20%20%20https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/separating-entity-definition)

and better way use the Separating Entity Definition

https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/separating-entity-definition

Comment: Ok, i fixed the entity definition, but the query still not work. What is the way to create a condition to a many to many relation?

Comment: the better way use this method : 
`this.find({where:{categoryId: filter.categoryId},relation:['categories'])`